# How to parse local JSON file in assets?

Tags: android, json, android-assets

I have a JSON file in my assets folder. That file has one object with an array. The array has 150+ objects with each having three strings.

For each of these 150+ objects I want to extract each string and create a java model object with it passing the three strings. All the tutorials I'm finding on android JSON parsing are fetching the JSON from a url which I don't want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Why does it matter *where* you get the JSON from? The tutorials are actually *getting a string*, and you create `new JSONObject(String)`... So, load the *assets File to a String*

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry if noob question, but do you always need to convert the  JSON file into a string and then parse the string? You can directly parse the JSON file?

Comment: It's understandable question :) You can parse an InputStream using `JsonReader` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Answer (score 39):

you should use **[Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson)**  as **json parser**.

add this dependency in app gradle file :

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

create  raw folder in res folder. then copy your json file  to raw folder.(its better to use raw folder instead of assets). for example you have this json file named **my_json.json**

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "name": "Faraz Khonsari",
      "age": 24
    },
    {
      "name": "John Snow",
      "age": 28
    },
    {
      "name": "Alex Kindman",
      "age": 29
    }
  ]
}
```

then create your **model class**:

```
public class MyModel {
        @SerializedName("list")
        public ArrayList<MyObject> list;

       static public class MyObject {
            @SerializedName("name")
            public String name;
            @SerializedName("age")
            public int age;
        }
    }
```

then you should create a function to read your json file :

```
public String inputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            String json = new String(bytes);
            return json;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

then read  your json file:

```
String myJson=inputStreamToString(mActivity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_json));
```

then convert json string to model:

```
MyModel myModel = new Gson().fromJson(myJson, MyModel.class);
```

now your Json have been converted to a model ! **Congratulation!**

Comment: and how do i Use:    MyModel myModel = new Gson().fromJson(myJson, MyModel.class); ? or how do I acces to the propierties model

Comment: @xx_name for example if u want access name of first object : myModel.list.get(0).name

Comment: @farazkhonsari "its better to use raw folder instead of assets". Explain the line please.

Answer (score 9):

Previous answers work well, but if you're using Kotlin you can do it in a very nice and concise way by using the classes in the kotlin.io package.

```
val objectArrayString: String = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.my_object).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
val objectArray = Gson().fromJson(objectArrayString, MyObject::class.java)
```

You could even turn into a nice generic extension method if you want for easy reuse:

```
inline fun <reified T> Context.jsonToClass(@RawRes resourceId: Int): T =
        Gson().fromJson(resources.openRawResource(resourceId).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }, T::class.java)
```

Which you would then simply call like this:

```
context.jsonToClass<MyObject>(R.raw.my_object)
```

Answer (score 3):

first you need to read the json file from assets , you can use this method

```
public String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
  BufferedReader reader = null;
  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(fileName), "UTF-8")); 

  String content = "";
  String line;
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
  {
     content = content + line
  }

  return content;

}
```

then

```
String jsonFileContent = readFile("json_in_assets.json");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonFileContent);
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
  JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  Integer id = jsonObj.getInt("id");
  String name = jsonObj.getString("name");
  String phone = jsonObj.getString("phone");
  persons.add(new Person(id , name , phone));
}
```

Comment: Could also parse the InputStream directly. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Answer (score 0):

Put your json file in raw folder and whit Gson library you can pars json :

```
Reader reader= new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json_test));
JsonElement json=new Gson().fromJson(reader,JsonElement.class);
```

You can use this JsonElemnt for Gson or if you want json as string you can do this :

```
String jsonString=json.toString();
```