# How to convert HashMap to Json and back, using Gson?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, hashmap, gson

### Background

I just want to save and load some JSON as a string, originated from a HashMap of `<LocalDate,Int>`

### The problem

While I succeed to generate JSON string from HashMap, I fail to do the opposite, of generating the HashMap from the JSON string.

### What I've tried

This is what I do to convert to Json string:

```
val gson = Gson()
val type = object:TypeToken<Map<LocalDate, Int>>(){}.type
val map: HashMap<LocalDate, Int> = HashMap()
val today = LocalDate.now()
map[today] = 1
val jsonStr = gson.toJson(map, type) // example of what this has: "{"2024-01-01":1}"
```

I can also use this to see that indeed it should be possible to parse the string:

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonStr)
```

And also to check the value from it:

val countForToday = jsonObject.getInt(today.toString())

However, when I use this (after looking [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46762398/878126)):

```
var newMap: Map<LocalDate, Int> = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, object : TypeToken<Map<LocalDate, Int>>() {}.type)
```

I get this exception:

```
Method threw 'com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException' exception.
IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line...
```

What I've tried, and all failed, based on what I saw from other examples:

1. I tried to use `GsonBuilder().create()` instead of just `Gson()`. I don't think this should matter, though maybe `Gson()` could be a singleton to be used everywhere, and probably even be thread-safety too.
2. Use `Map` instead of HashMap, use `Any` instead of `Int`, use `?` (nullable). All various combinations I could thing of...

Right now I use this workaround, of not using Gson for the conversion back to HashMap:

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonStr)
val hashHap = HashMap<LocalDate, Int>()
jsonObject.keys().forEach { key: String ->
    val date = LocalDate.parse(key)
    val value = jsonObject.getInt(key)
    hashHap[date] = value
}
```

This works, but I want to know why the Gson one failed.

### The question

What is going on? Why can't I do this simple conversion back to HashMap/Map (using Gson) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are having problem with converting `LocalDate`.
The problem is `GSON` does not seem to recognize `LocalDate` objects.
You need to have a custom Date serializer and deserializer.
It'll look somrthing like:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

/**
 *
 * @author asgar
 */
public class LocalDateConverter implements JsonSerializer<LocalDate>, JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(LocalDate src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(src));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.parse(json.getAsString(), LocalDate::from);
    }
}
```

After that you can use it. Here is a sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

        builder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<LocalDate>() {}.getType(), new LocalDateConverter());
        
        Gson gson1 = builder.create();

        String jsonString = "{\"2023-01-01\":10,\"2023-02-15\":20,\"2023-05-08\":15,\"2023-08-20\":30}";
        
        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<LocalDate, Integer>>() {}.getType();
        
        Map<LocalDate, Integer> map = gson1.fromJson(jsonString, type);

        System.out.println("HashMap1: " + map);
    }
```

For more info, please refer to [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-typeadapter-for-inaccessibleobjectexception/)

Comment: This works. Still, I have questions: 1. LocalDate is already Serializable, and the creation of Json string succeeded from HashMap, so why can't I do the opposite? Shouldn't it work in both directions? 2. Why not use `LocalDate.parse` in deserialize function, meaning `LocalDate.parse(json.getAsString())` ? Same goes for `serialize`, which you could use "toString" on the LocalDate, no? 3. All parameters of the functions in LocalDateConverter are non-nullable, right? 4.

Comment: @androiddeveloper `LocalDate` alone (and without custom adapter) serializes as `{}`. In this very case it was `String` because of this line (https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/MapTypeAdapterFactory.java#L221). `complexMapKeySerialization` is `false` by default, and `LocalDate` has `.toString()` overridden, that's why `String.valueOf(entry.getKey())` returned `"2024-01-01"`

Comment: This answers why it got converted to String, right? But what about the rest of the questions? Why isn't it working anyway as it's Serializable? Why did you choose this implementation of using DateTimeFormatter , and are all parameters here are non-null (I think they are, according to docs) ?

Comment: "Why isn't it working anyway as it's Serializable?" @androiddeveloper, because `java.io.Serializable` is for [Java Object Serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/serialization/serial-arch.html) which is completely unrelated to how Gson works (it just accesses fields using reflection if there is no built-in adapter).

Comment: The code in this answer is a bit misleading; as pointed out by @VladGuriev by default Gson uses `toString()` for Map keys, so `LocalDateConverter.serialize` is not actually called, but `LocalDate.toString()` happens to produce the same output. As mentioned in the [user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/UserGuide.md#maps-examples) you can use [`GsonBuilder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization()) to make sure it is also used for serialization.

Comment: @Marcono1234 About Serializable , ok. About the rest, what do you mean? There is a better/alternative answer? Please write it down as a new one

Comment: @androiddeveloper you can take this answer and add `builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization()` before `Gson gson1 = builder.create();` from the second snippet. Thus, you *a)* add `LocalDateConverter` with (de)serialization rules and *b)* force Gson to use this converter when `LocalDate` is a key in `Map` (because, by default, `Gson` uses `.toString()` in this case)